# sequence of activity flows in android fragments app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Here are some facts about my app followed by a question

My app has two fragments.

My app creates certain file structure and documents on its first launch and it takes time, thus I am using `AsyncTask` class method to display `ProgressDialog` while the file structure is created. This is done in `onCreate` method of my MainActivity just like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Loading...");

        File testFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/myNewFolder");
        if (!testFile.exists()) {
            new MyTask(progress).execute();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        } else
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

The problem is that `onActivityCreated` method of one of my `Fragment`s starts running  BEFORE `new MyTask(progress).execute();` is finished. This causes errors and problems.

Why this `onActivityCreated` method of one of my `Fragment`s runs BEFORE
`new MyTask(progress).execute();`???

Please do not assume that there are some silly mistakes that i didnt take into account xx

This is my MyTask class

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public MyTask(ProgressDialog progress) {
        // this.progress = progress;
    }

    public void onPreExecute() {
        progress.show();
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        progress.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        CreateFileStructure();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I need to create that file structure before anything else happens - that is why I am using this `ProgressDialog`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I might be missing the point, but the whole point of an AsyncTask is that it runs independently of the Activity lifecycle.  You should use the onPostExecute callback to call a method in your activity to update your data views or whatever it is you do with the data.  Your activity should deal with being created before it's data is available. The onPostExecute callback is also a good place to dismiss your progress dialog.

Comment: Simon, could you please take a look on the updated question and suggest what i am doing wrong. I need to create that file structure before anything else happens.

Comment: What do you mean "before anything else happens"?  Your activity is created and displayed, but the user cannot interact with it until the progress dialog is dismissed which happens when your data has been loaded.  Please explain the problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks, Simon. Your first comment gave me an understanding of what the hell is going on, and now it works and i shall post my tweaked code in a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that works for me - the `ProgressDialog` dialog is displayed while file structure and files are created, everything else (fragments, etc.) happens afterwards.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Loading...");

        File testFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/myNewFolder");
        if (!testFile.exists())
            new MyTask(progress).execute();
        else
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        public MyTask(ProgressDialog progress) {
            // this.progress = progress;
        }

        public void onPreExecute() {
            progress.show();
        }

        public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

            progress.dismiss();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            CreateFileStructure();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see the life cycle of fragment, the view of the fragment's are instantiated on the onCreate method of the activity which contains the fragment.

For that reason you are getting that error.